# Facebook json url to retrieve event wall feed

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm currently trying to pull the wall from this event page: https://www.facebook.com/event.php?eid=139373546157232, but I'm not sure how I go about getting the graph url to use in an ajax request.. I want to get it in json format and I also need the auth token.. This event is not private so should I need a auth token just to read the data?

I have used this url to get the event info: https://graph.facebook.com/139373546157232 but the object has limited data...

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Events have a number of 'connections' to give you more data:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/event/

Unfortunately it seems you do need an access token to access the interesting parts of the info. However, a public access token from any user should be sufficient if the event is public. Perhaps generate an offline access token as yourself and store it permanently and try using that if you need to query event info in a non-connected-user context.

Comment: Where do I get the generic access token from? I've read some documentation on it but it doesn't state where I retrieve it.. unless I'm missing something?

Comment: I'm using the information in this context: http://www.delete-cardiff.co.uk/new_site

Comment: If I were you I'd put together a very simple example that requests offline_access and manage_pages, then simply write down the access token in a config file and use that. :) Let me know if you need an example.

Comment: I'll have a little look through the documentation and put something togeather this afternoon.. I'll let you know how I get on.. thank you :)

Comment: Hi,I came back to this.. and I'm still none the wiser as to how I get the access_token needed top retrieve the wall info... Any ideas?

Comment: you can get access_token at this url https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer

Comment: I've used the access_token I got from the above url and when I view it in the browser I get the data coming back: https://graph.facebook.com/139373546157232/feed?access_token=AAACEdEose0cBAGB0dcp6eG523JAM9QZB0UKZBIKv5P4C3shBCDJoAVEeKN1bQ1UeI5eWDhz5l4kidQZAyZCgHAJdfVjCNxGWyZCtDlGbKmwZDZD